# How to pass an array to OpenCV dnn

Tags: python, opencv, openvino

I'm using OpenVino pre-trained models for action driver action detection...

the driver action detection pipeline consists of two parts, encoder and decoder which can be used with openCV dnn class.
Encoder takes an image of shape (1,3,224,224) and produces a features vector of shape (1,512,1,1), then the decoder takes input of 16 frames of shape (1,16,512) and produces an one-hot vector representing the probability of each class.

My question is how to feed an array of shape (1,16,512) to a the decoder network...
when I used `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage()` it throws an exception

```
blob=cv.dnn.blobFromImage(vectors,size=(16,512))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0-openvino) ../opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:669: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'arithm_op
```

Can someone help , please.

Comment: Can you please share a piece of the code where you construct the `vectors` variable? I guess something is wrong with a way you are doing it. By the way, the decoder network takes 3-d input ([BxTxC]), so at least you need to fix `size=(16,512)`=>`size=(1,16,512)`

Comment: There is an action recognition Python demo that you can refer to for the decoder pre-processing. Alternatively, are you willing to share your code with the encoder post-processing and decoder pre-processing steps for us to look into this? Here is a link to the demo:  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_demos_python_demos_action_recognition_README.html